# Removing "Account Name" field from Contact

Tags: standard-objects, data-model

In Salesforce, the standard Contact object holds a field "Account Name".
I do not want to have this field in the Contact object or al least on the Contact details view.
The reason is I am linking Accounts and Contacts into a many to many relationship via a junction object and do not want that link to a single account.
I do not also want to design an entire custom object for Contacts, for this simple purpose.
Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Note: Even when you *hide* the field, you best make sure that the account field is populated *somehow* (e.g. by a trigger). If you do not, you will *not* be able to easily see or share those contacts across users, because they are considered "private contacts." A better solution is to use Person Accounts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Do This,

Just Remove Field Level Security for all the Profile( Including System Admin ), Once you removed it will be there in page layout editor, but It won't be "Visible" In End User View.
[image]

Contact view

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. You could look into using [Contact Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contactroles.htm) instead of your junction object, as this is Salesforce standard solution to link a Contact to multiple Accounts.